# Proof about the kernel of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove that if $\ker A \neq \{ 0\}$ where $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$, then $\ker (BA) \neq\{ 0\}$ for all Matrices $B \in \mathbb{K}^{k\times n}$

I proved that this does not hold for $\ker A = \{ 0\}$, but I am struggling here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\ker(BA) \neq \{0\}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited it.

Comment: If $x \in \ker A$ then $Ax = 0 $ so $BAx = 0$ and hence $x \in \ker(BA)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did.

Let $\vec{k} \in \ker A/\{0\}$

We have $A\vec{k} = \vec{0}$. We simply right multiply by $B$. We now get $BA\vec{k} = B\vec{0}$, giving us $BA\vec{k} = \vec{0}$. Hence $\vec{k} \in \ker(BA)$ and by the definition of $\vec{k}$ we have that $\ker(BA) \neq \{0\}$

Comment: Thank you, I did not think about just right mulitplying.

Answer (score 1):

If the kernel of $A$ is not just the zero vector, $\vec{0}$, that means there is a nonzero vector $v$ such that $Av=\vec{0}$. Now check what happens to $(BA)v$.

$(BA)v= B(Av)= B\vec{0} = \vec{0}$.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Comment: Would this change for $\ker (AB) \neq\{ 0\}$ where B is an m x k matrix?

Comment: Yes, it would change. I would recommend asking the question separately if you want details. Also, you would need to change the dimensions of the matrices for $AB$ to make sense.